# Gimp: making edges less smooth

Tags: gimp, inkscape

Most questions are about smoothing edges. I would like the opposite.

I have this map:

[image: original]

I would like a plugin/filter to make edges more rough. Something along this:

[image: mockup]

EDIT: I think the trouble I am getting (see comment below) is because of my bitmap tracing. Here's the options I am using. Please tell me if there's something wrong!

[image: dialog1]

[image: dialog2]

Comment: Have you tried with Smooth and Quick sketch or Gimpressionist? Basing on your example, this seems more a vector tool work. Is the original source a bitmap or a vector? In Inkscape you can convert the curves to lines, simplify the path and increase the width of the border (references are [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html)). Or you can use the [sketch](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-Sketch.html) effect.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini you are right - this is the job for a vectorial program. It actually fits my use case better as well. I ended up using Inkscape, and stroking it manually... If you'd like please post your comment as an answer and I will confirm it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on your example, this seems more a [vector tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics_editor) work.

If the original source is a vector, you can edit this with [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/). If the image is a bitmap, you can import and [trace](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) it (as in this example).

Now, you can [edit the path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html), it's composed by nodes:

[image: nodes]

Select all the nodes and **simplify** the path by hitting **Ctrl+L**

[image: simplified path]

With the node selected, convert the lines in segments by hitting the proper icon:

[image: hit it]

Change the [width of the stroke](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html) and obtain the final image:

[image: too rough]

Too rough? You can **simplify less** or adjust the nodes manually before convert the curves in lines:

[image: less simplified]

As alternative you can use the [sketch](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-Sketch.html) effect (*Path... Path effects... +*):

[image: add path effect]

You can play with the parameters (it's one of the [live path effects](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects.html)):

[image: parameters]

And obtain another rough image:

[image: sketched image]

Comment: Paolo, sorry for not commenting early. Been busy... But this was excellent, thanks!! Something weird is that after tracing the bitmap, and selecting the nodes, then I do simplify and instead of your beautiful image with nice nodes, I get this ugly thing... :P https://www.dropbox.com/s/retstafsgj9izb4/map.svg

Comment: I have added to my post, screenshots of my Trace dialog, which may be where the problem lies...

Comment: @RicardoCruz Your map is not ugly, in my opinion there is a kind of artistic. For a more accurate trace you can select *Colors* or *Brightness steps* in "Multiple scans" section of the parameters. And remember that you can avoid to trace and start from a pretty ready [svg map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_map_of_Europe.svg) of Europe.

Comment: But Paolo, what is strange is that the thickness from my lines is not uniform. They are not simple lines like yours, they seem to have curved thickness... it is hard to explain... I have upgraded already to the latest stable version; will try in a Windows workstation. (The problem with the other maps is that I want only continental contour, not countries. But I can also try to find a SVG version of such a map, yes.)

Comment: The thickness is uniform, but you have an inner path and an outer path, hence the strange effect. If you want only the continental contour, is very simple: you can try to start from the Wikimedia Common's svg map of Europe, *ungroup* it, remove the background rectangle, *select* the desired nations, *scale* them a little and perform an *union*.

Comment: Okay, you just gave me a short course into vectorial drawing through all these comments. When I have some time, I will do it. Thank you! :)

Comment: You are welcome ;-). You can try also to increase the borders until they overlap, transform the strokes into path, break apart them and then perform an union.